# Immutable.js: Is this an expected hashCode collision, or a bug?

Tags: immutable.js

So I was playing around with [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)'s [`hashCode`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/hashCode) function, and I pretty soon found a collision:

```js
Immutable.Map({ hello: 1, world: 2 }).hashCode() === Immutable.Map({ world: 1, hello: 2 }).hashCode() // true
```

Now the docs clearly state (emphasis mine):

> If two values have the same hashCode, **they are not guaranteed to be equal**.

But I'm just wondering if this "trivial" example is a "valid" collision, or a bug? Or am I missing something super obvious?

Comment: Seems to just be a collision, as unlikely as it would seem for this particular example.

Comment: Right. It's strange though that making lots of different changes (ex: change 1 to 2, and 2 to 3, or change 'hello' to 'hellop') also produces collisions. I'd think collisions are super rare. I guess not!

Comment: Ya, I was playing around with it [here](https://codepen.io/nashio/pen/RrvQYQ?editors=0011)(damn, it didn't save my stuff). Any small change had the expected effect. You could look up the source of `hashCode` though, and walk through the math of it to verify.